# Get-Content : Cannot bind argument to parameter 'Path' because it is null

Tags: powershell

I'm getting error while running code. CSV file is already available at location.

```
Cannot convert value "System.Collections.Specialized.OrderedDictionary" to type "System.Management.Automation.LanguagePrimitives+InternalPSCustomObject". Error: "Cannot process 
argument because the value of argument "name" is not valid. Change the value of the "name" argument and run the operation again."
At line:4 char:13
+             $Object = [PSCustomObject]@{
+             ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
    + CategoryInfo          : InvalidArgument: (:) [], RuntimeException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : InvalidCastConstructorException
 
A null key is not allowed in a hash literal.
At line:6 char:17
+                 $_.Parameter    =   $_.Status
+                 ~~~~~~~~~~~~
    + CategoryInfo          : InvalidOperation: (System.Collecti...deredDictionary:OrderedDictionary) [], RuntimeException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : InvalidNullKey
 
A null key is not allowed in a hash literal.
At line:6 char:17
+                 $_.Parameter    =   $_.Status
+                 ~~~~~~~~~~~~
    + CategoryInfo          : InvalidOperation: (System.Collecti...deredDictionary:OrderedDictionary) [], RuntimeException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : InvalidNullKey
 
A null key is not allowed in a hash literal.
At line:6 char:17
+                 $_.Parameter    =   $_.Status
+                 ~~~~~~~~~~~~
    + CategoryInfo          : InvalidOperation: (System.Collecti...deredDictionary:OrderedDictionary) [], RuntimeException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : InvalidNullKey
 
A null key is not allowed in a hash literal.
At line:6 char:17
+                 $_.Parameter    =   $_.Status
+                 ~~~~~~~~~~~~
    + CategoryInfo          : InvalidOperation: (System.Collecti...deredDictionary:OrderedDictionary) [], RuntimeException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : InvalidNullKey
```

```
$Results = Get-ChildItem -Path "C:\Kumar\*.csv" |Select-Object -Property ComputerName, Parameter, Status | ForEach-Object {
    Get-Content $_.FullName | ConvertFrom-Csv | ForEach-Object {
        if ($null -ne $_.ComputerName) {
            $Object = [PSCustomObject]@{
                ComputerName    =   $_.ComputerName
                $_.Parameter    =   $_.Status
            }
        } else {
            $Object | Add-Member -MemberType NoteProperty -Name $_.Parameter -Value $_.Status
        }
    }
    $Object
}

$Results | Export-Csv -Path "C:\temp\Results.csv" -NoTypeInformation
```

Comment: Showing just the code without giving details is not helpful. You must state the problem you are encountering. Please [Edit](https://superuser.com/posts/1751166/edit) your question and clarify. See [How do I ask a good question?](https://superuser.com/help/how-to-ask).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You get the error because this line of code `Select-Object -Property ComputerName, Parameter, Status` is placed before you have read the file's content. When you pipe the result to `Get-Content`, the output is not a file's path. You should put that line inside the 1st `ForEach` clause to avoid any error.

```ps
$Results = Get-ChildItem -Path "C:\Kumar\*.csv" | ForEach-Object {
    Get-Content $_.FullName | ConvertFrom-Csv | Select-Object -Property ComputerName, Parameter, Status | ForEach-Object {
        if ($null -ne $_.ComputerName) {
            $Object = [PSCustomObject]@{
                ComputerName    =   $_.ComputerName
                $_.Parameter    =   $_.Status
            }
        } else {
            $Object | Add-Member -MemberType NoteProperty -Name $_.Parameter -Value $_.Status
        }
    }
    $Object
}

$Results | Export-Csv -Path "C:\temp\Results.csv" -NoTypeInformation
```

Comment: Now error is:- `A null key is not allowed in a hash literal.
At line:6 char:17
+                 $_.Parameter    =   $_.Status
+                 ~~~~~~~~~~~~
    + CategoryInfo          : InvalidOperation: (System.Collecti...deredDictionary:OrderedDictionary) [], RuntimeException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : InvalidNullKey`

Comment: That's another issue that's not related to the main issue of this question. However, are you sure that new object as a property named Parameter?

Comment: check the CSV file attached in question.