# Want to add PCName manually by using $env:computername. i'm trying to add PCName header in exported file without making any changes to original file

Tags: powershell

Want to add PCName manually by using $env:computername in the exported excel. But getting below error.

```
$destinationPath= "C:\temp\Excelfile.csv"
$info = Import-Csv -Path "C:\kumar.csv" | 
    ?{ !([string]::IsNullOrEmpty($_.Parameter))}
    Select-Object -Property PCName, Parameter, Status |
        Sort-Object -Property Status |ConvertFrom-Csv

        $NewCSV = @"
$($info.PCName="$env.computername" -join ',')
$($info.Parameter -join ',')
$($info.Status -join ',')
"@ | ConvertFrom-Csv


$NewCSV |Export-Csv -Path $destinationPath
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Get-Content : Cannot bind argument to parameter 'Path' because it is null](https://superuser.com/questions/1751166/get-content-cannot-bind-argument-to-parameter-path-because-it-is-null)

Comment: @Toto this is not the same question. Here i'm trying to add PCName header in exported file without making any changes to original file. Check the csv data and desired output of both question.

Comment: You are trying to pivot only some data and add new columns. None of what you have here will work, because you are not making any effort to extract only what you want and add what you do. You do this with string extraction and then use calculated properties to do the rest, then create your output. Also remember, the rules are, do not use pictures; use text. Folks do like retyping stuff. If that is your file layout, you really need to reconsider how to approach this.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To just add stuff to your current thing, it's just this:

```
Clear-Host
@'
"Parameter","Version","Status"
"Windows 11","20H2","Compliant"
"Patching","NA","Compliant"
'@ | 
ConvertFrom-Csv | 
Export-Csv -Path 'D:\Temp\PCDetails.csv' -NoTypeInformation



Import-Csv -Path 'D:\Temp\PCDetails.csv' | 
Select-Object -Property @{
    Name       = 'PCName'
    Expression = {$env:COMPUTERNAME}
},
@{
    Name       = 'OSName'
    Expression = {$PSItem.Parameter}
},
@{
    Name       = 'OSVersion'
    Expression = {$PSItem.Version}
}, Status
# Results
<#
PCName OSName     OSVersion Status   
------ ------     --------- ------   
PC70   Windows 11 20H2      Compliant
PC70   Patching   NA        Compliant
#>
```

Note simply use a calculated property as per my comment.

***Again, with a single record***, you can do this very q&d (quick and dirty) ***non-elegant*** way:

```
Clear-Host
$PCHealthDetails = (
Get-Content -Path 'D:\Temp\PCDetails.csv' | 
Select-Object -Skip 1
) -join ',' | 
ConvertFrom-Csv -Header H0, H1, H2, H3, H4, H5 | 
Select-Object -Property @{
    Name       = 'ComputerName'
    Expression = {$env:COMPUTERNAME}
}, '*' 


[PSCustomObject]@{
    ComputerName        = $PCHealthDetails.ComputerName
    $PCHealthDetails.H0 = $PCHealthDetails.H2
    $PCHealthDetails.H3 = $PCHealthDetails.H5
}

# Results
<#
ComputerName Windows 11 Patching 
------------ ---------- -------- 
PC70         Compliant  Compliant
#>
```

***Note you cannot use the original CSV with Import-CSV, because of the data manipulation/layout you say/show you want.***

Again, there is a lot of guessing you are leaving us with a lot here, as more than one record, with a different Windows OS version, this then would not work with this method; because the header banner would not change

```
Clear-Host
@'
"Parameter","Version","Status"
"Windows 11","20H2","Compliant"
"Patching","NA","Compliant"
"Windows 10","RollUp","Compliant"
"Patching","NA","Compliant"
'@ | 
ConvertFrom-Csv | 
Export-Csv -Path 'D:\Temp\PCDetails.csv' -NoTypeInformation
```

You'd end up having to do stuff like this instead, to show all records and OS versions checked:

```
Clear-Host
(Get-Content -Path 'D:\Temp\PCDetails.csv' -ReadCount 3) -replace '"Parameter","Version","Status"' | 
ForEach{

    $PCHealthDetails = ($PSItem -Join ',') -replace '" "', '","' | 
    ConvertFrom-Csv -Header H0, H1, H2, H3, H4, H5

    [PSCustomObject]@{
        ComputerName = $env:COMPUTERNAME
        Version      = $PCHealthDetails.H0
        Status       = $PCHealthDetails.H2
        $PCHealthDetails.H3 = $PCHealthDetails.H5
    }
}
# Results
<#
ComputerName Version    Status    Patching 
------------ -------    ------    -------- 
PC70         Windows 11 Compliant Compliant
PC70         Windows 10 Compliant Compliant
#>
```

Comment: We are going in right direction. But my requirement is as below.

Comment: Point of note: this layout, meaning your stated output, does not match what you initially said you wanted. If you did this with more than one entry, this can/will be problematic. Why are you only showing what appears to be one record?